# selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Service chromedriver unexpectedly exited. Status code was: -5

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, odoo-13

Can anyone help me?

When I run the method like a simple script of python it works, but when I call from other aplication (in this case `odoo13`) I get the error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: 
Message: Service chromedriver unexpectedly exited. Status code was: -5
psdt:
```

I searched the code error but I can't find nothing.

Please HELP.

This is the code

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome("chromedriver")

    driver.get("some ip")

    driver.find_element(By.ID, "W0005_USECOD").send_keys(username)
    driver.find_element(By.ID, "W0005_CLAVE").send_keys(password)

    driver.find_element(By.NAME, "W0005BTNLOGIN").click()

    error_msg = "Clave no es correcta"

    errors = driver.find_elements(By.ID, "W0005TB_MENSAJE")

    driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//option[@value='1111']").click()

    driver.find_element(By.NAME, "W0005BTNACEPTAR").click()

    driver.find_element(By.NAME, "_PGMICO_0001").click()

    element = driver.find_element(By.ID, "webfx-tree-object-25-anchor")

    action = ActionChains(driver)

    action.double_click(on_element=element)

    action.perform()

    driver.find_element(By.ID, "webfx-tree-object-26-anchor").click()

    dni = nro

    driver.find_element(By.ID, "_PERDOCIDENNUM").send_keys(dni)

    driver.find_element(By.NAME, "BUTTON1").click()
```

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: first you could use `print()` or `logging` to see which part of code is executed and what you have in variables. It is called `"print debuging"` and it can help to see where is the problem.